# React Native Error (Invalid Element Type)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

when starting my App on my iOS device I get this error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but gor: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the
file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of 'App'.

```
This error is located at:
  in App (created by ExpoRoot)
  in RNCAppearanceProvider (at src/index.tsx:70)
  in AppearanceProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
  in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
  in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
  in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:124)
  in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
  in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

When this is my App.js:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  createDrawerNavigator,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Move to the Details Page"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go back to the Home" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

// Drawer navigation:
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Since I am not using a class the statement "Check the render method of `App`." shouldn't be be useful to me.. I googled a bit and found out that, as a common error in React Native, can be resolved by adjusting imports and exports but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bad importing NavigationContainer, for avoid types problem I recommend typescript :)

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Answer (score 1):

NavigationContainer not exported from @react-navigation/drawer .[See docs here !](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/)

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```